# Cutting in bash everything around a string

Tags: bash, grep

- I have exported a lot of JSON files, almost 100.
- They are basically huge one-liners.
- Each file has `"uid":"random"`.
- How to cut only `"uid":"random"` part for all files from the master directory?
- I've tried with `grep {}` but can't workaround the quotes on the uid and the value.
- Also, I tried to cut it but still the quotes are the problem.
- Line structure:

  ..."title":"Random title","uid":"r4nd0muid","version":X},"overwrite": true}

Comment: It's doable with sed and awk, however without knowing the structure of the lines, one cannot properly suggest any code to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements: it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself.  Please [edit] your question to show [your attempt far](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and you'll be much more likely to receive answers that help you progress.  Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use anything but JSON aware tools for processing JSON files and post a proper sample for testing but to *workaround the quotes on the uid and the value* on the posted string:

```
$ grep -o \"uid\":\"[^\"]*\" foodata
"uid":"r4nd0muid"
```

Basically `"uid":"[^"]*"`, ie. after `"uid":"` all non-`"` and a `"`.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a lot easier to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which is a search and transformation tool for JSON files.

Given the file `test.json`:

```
{
  "uuid": "whatever"
}
```

You can extract just the `uuid` field with:

```sh
jq '.uuid' test.json
# output: "whatever"
```

Comment: That's a nice suggestion. But for some reason not getting the result (which i know it's in the file). jq '.uid' file returns null value every time on every file.

Comment: It looks like your `uuid` field may not be in the top of the object tree in the file. A more complete example of your file contents would resolve this.